# Firebase Functions: when to call initializeApp/deleteApp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a variety of functions for [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that use things derived from `firebase-admin/app`'s `initializeApp()`. Since multiple functions use this, I had the idea of calling `initializeApp()` close to the beginning of the Typescript/Javascript. Like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
...
const app = initializeApp();
...
export const activeUser = https.onCall(
    async (email: string, ctx: CallableContext) => {
        ...
        const auth = getAuth(app);
        const firestore = getFirestore(app);
        try {
            const user = await auth.getUserByEmail(email);
            const snpsht = await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
...
export const userExists = https.onCall(
    async (email: string, ctx: CallableContext) => {
        if (!emulating() && forbiddenOrigin(ctx)) {
            return `${ERRORFLAG}: forbidden`;
        }
        const auth = getAuth(app);
...
```

A testing headache showed me that I forgot about calling `deleteApp(app)`.

Is `deleteApp()` necessary, or will the app be deleted as a side effect of Cloud tearing down the function?

Should `initializeApp()`/`deleteApp()` be called within each function where an app is needed, ie within `activeUser` and `userExists` in my above example?

Is there any way to tell Cloud Functions to run setup/teardown code before running a given function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to deleteApp is not necessary.  When a Cloud Functions instance terminates, all memory gets shut down with it (which is what deleteApp would do).  The entire server instance is completely gone.

You only need to call deleteApp if you are controlling a process that needs to continue after the call to deleteApp with the Firebase resources freed from memory.  Cloud Functions does not meet this criteria since you don't control the process startup or shutdown.

Comment: As an addendum to this, a deployed Cloud Function operates under much tighter restrictions than the local Firebase emulators which provide conveniences for the sake of keeping things simple and getting you going. The emulators don't simulate the teardown behaviour described above, the severe throttling when idle, or load each function in isolation from the other functions (function A and function B may be in the same code block, but when called upon when deployed, are executed by different functions instances).